# Why AutoIt succeeds sending input to directx application and SendInput/SendMessage doesn't?

Tags: c#, windows, directx, autoit

Recently I made a program which sends keystrokes into a DirectX application.
The application changes the cursor when the user clicks a certain key. When I tried it with C# code (Window API) it did not work, but when I tried it with AutoIt it worked perfectly.

I wanted to know why it didn't work with C#. What are the differences of the code used (C# and AutoIt)?

I thought that AutoIt is an easy-to-use wrapper of Win API, but the results aren't showing that, so how were those functions built?

I hope that you guys can help me understand it more thoroughly, thanks.

Here is my code.

**C#:**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In] INPUT[] pInputs,int cbSize);
```

**AutoIt:**

```
Send("{F1 down}")
Sleep(300)
Send("{F1 up}")
```

The AutoIt code worked while C# code didn't work. Why?

Comment: As your question stands currently your are unlikely to get a good answer.  If you are having problems with code you wrote in AutoIt working differently than C# code, include the code for both and explicitly state what works in one and not in the other.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `SendInput()` and `SendMessage()` methods in C#.

I am an AutoIt and C# user so the functions I would use to replace AutoIt's `Send()` and `Sleep()` functions in C# would be [`keybd_event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is the `keybd_event` method:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

....
keybd_event(0x52, 0, 1 | 0, 0);
keybd_event(0x52, 0, 1 | 2, 0);
```

Check MSDN for a [table of virtual key codes and their values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx)